# Error in getOctD(x, offset, len) : invalid octal digit

Tags: r, octal, install.packages

I try to install packages (pdbDEMO actually and all the dependencies) and I am encountering an issue, that I cannot solve and I haven't found any solution about it.

I use the R command :

```
>install.packages("pbdDEMO", lib="C:/Users/xavier_520285/Desktop", type = "source")
```

Then all the 6 packages are downloaded, but not installed since I get 6 error messages :

```
Error in getOctD(x, offset, len) : invalid octal digit
```

I have absolutely no clue about how to fix it.

I would be very grateful with any helpful answer.

Comment: I have occasionally seen this; it seems to be some kind of file corruption issue, i.e. I have "solved" it by re-downloading/trying again.  Good luck ...

Comment: Not better... Thanks anyway !

Comment: Install **one** package at a time to see which one is throwing the error.  Then, if nothing else, you could try building that one from the source tarball.

Comment: that problem happens when the tar.gz is corrupted (for example when you try to download a tar.gz from github but not in raw format) check if the tar.gz is really a tar.gz otherwise redownload it

Answer (score 6):

As the post above suggests, your tar file is probably corrupt, or it's not a tar file at all.

The easiest way to check it on Linux is to use `file <filename>` command, a proper .tar.gz file will return something like this:

```
rJava_0.9-4.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix, last modified: Tue Mar 12 09:54:30 2013
```

When you are behind a proxy or a firewall and you don't have it properly configured on your computer, oftentimes you will download a html file or a proxy script instead of the file that you are looking for. You can even try to read it as text with `head` or `less`:

```
# head rhdfs_1.0.5.tar.gz
/* NCSC PAC v1.271  */
var Pt;
var Pc;
var ihost;
var NAPROXY="133.183.234.11";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you doing this with a firewall perhaps?  In my case the company's firewall was filtering the download, and ultimately, `wget http://cran.fhcrc.org/src/contrib/gdata_2.17.0.tar.gz` was downloading an html page from the firewall saying the download was blocked, but install.packages wasn't aware, it just knew that the file was not a valid tarball.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue when using an incompatible (older) version of R/Rstudio. It's worth trying to install an older version of the package via devtools::install_version()